# Understanding usage of not operator in :selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just came across this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h5a3j7yg/)** online. The JS looks like below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        return !$('#select1 option:selected').appendTo('#select2');
    });
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        return !$('#select2 option:selected').appendTo('#select1');
    });
});
```

**HTML** ::

```
<SELECT id="select1" name="select1" size="3"><OPTION value="1">Test 1</option><OPTION value="2">Test 2</option></select> 
<SELECT id="select2" name="select2"></select>
<br><input type="button" id="add" value="Add >>"><input type="button" id="remove" value="<< Remove">
```

Its basically just a piece of JS interchanging a select values. But what I don't understand is the usage of the `!` operator(not operator).

Now I understand that the not operator inverses the result, but in the above code what is it really doing? I am not understanding what the not operator is doing in the above fiddle and what impact it is having on the end result? Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a fancy way of doing:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
        $('#select1 option:selected').appendTo('#select2');
         return false;
});
```

the `return false` prevents default behavior of the button by cancelling the event.

Since an object will always be truthy, `!object` will be false and `$(selector)` returns an object

Comment: what is the effect with and without the `!` operator , i still don't get it :(

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik actually I thought so too ...never used it before

Comment: If you have to ask on SO what it does it might be a cool technique but it also isn't a very good one since people might not understand your code properly. I would strongly advice against using this in projects that aren't just your own playthings.